# Javascript: Back button vs manual refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, cross-browser

Is it possible to determine, in Javascript, the back button event vs entering an URL directly in the browser's nav bar?

For example if my browser history is:

- page 1 (`/page1`)
- page 2 (current page, `/page2`)

I would like to have different logic if I press back button going to page 1, compared to entering `page1` in the browser's URL bar.

Comment: do you mean when the user clicks on the back button its refreshing (reloading) the page?

Comment: Could you explain your need for this? Since I cannot see the way where you could notice this, and do something in this short time, if there even is a way to do it. Maybe we can help you achieve this in another way?

Comment: Good Day What have you tried so far? Are you using any frameworks like Angular? You can look at window.onbeforeunload, although I'm pretty sure that will go off from Back and Refresh. If you want to figure out if either Back / Forward is used, you can read performance.navigation.type. Thanks

Comment: @AntonioErdeljac I added more context.

Comment: @elnatanvazana I added more context.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Like you're saying `onbeforeunload` gets called in back and manual refresh so there's no difference there. Using `performance.navigation.type` provides also the same result.